# remove all existing breakpoints

Tags: lauterbach

Is there a command to remove all existing breakpoints within a script file?

A single breakpoint can be deleted as follows:

```
break.delete 0x12345
```

So when I start my script I don't know which ones are active and I want to remove them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete *all* breakpoints simply use

```
Break.Delete
```

without any parameters.

Alternatively you can use the command `Break.RESet` which clears all breakpoints *and* resets all global break point settings to their defaults.